# PhpMyAdmin Installation error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, installation, ubuntu

I have installed apache,mysql,php and phpmyadmin in my kubuntu 13.10 32 bit. I can access *localhost* and *localhost/info.php* successfully. But while loading phpmyadmin, the browser shows as follows.

Please help me to fix this error[image: shows this window while loadinh phpmyadmin]

Comment: Did you changed any folder permissins to 777 ?

Comment: yes chmod 777 -R /var/www ; but shows error chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www/’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www/config’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www/info.php’: Operation not permitted

Comment: you dont have enough permission to access it. so enter as root user by the command sudo -i

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin, simply by downloading the source file and uncompressing to `/var/www` or with a package manager?

Answer (score 1):

I think after adding `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to the file **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** you are not resetting the file pemission.

So reset the file permission to `555` by running

```
sudo chmod 555 apache2.conf
```